# error when trying to test a component with dialog No provider for MdDialogRef

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to write a spec for a component that uses the Material 2 dialog. The component itself works, the problem comes when testing it.

When launching the tests I get this error `Error: No provider for MdDialogRef!`. I've looked around and found a bunch of different solutions, but none worked.

### Here's the component that uses the dialog:

```
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sfw-confirm-dialog',
    template: `
    <h4 style="text-align:center">{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <button type="button" md-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">{{confirmButtonText}}</button>
        <button type="button" md-raised-button (click)="dialogRef.close(false)">{{cancelButtonText}}</button>
    </div> 
    `,
})
export class ConfirmDialog {
    public title: string;
    public message: string;

    public confirmButtonText = 'Ok';
    public cancelButtonText = 'Cancel';

    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ConfirmDialog>) { }
}
```

### Here's the module for that component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule, MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { ConfirmDialog } from './confirm-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ConfirmDialog,
    ],
    exports: [
        ConfirmDialog
    ],
    providers: [
        MdDialogRef
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ConfirmDialog
    ]
})
export class DialogModule { }
```

### And the test:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ConfirmDialog } from './confirm-dialog.component';

describe('ConfirmDialog', () => {
    let comp: ConfirmDialog;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfirmDialog>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                MaterialModule.forRoot(),
            ],
            declarations: [
                ConfirmDialog
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfirmDialog);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create component', () => {
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I've followed the example provided on the docs of  material.angular.io am I missing something maybe?

The version of angular that I'm using is 4.1.1 while the version of material is 2.0.0-beta.2. I'm however planning to move to the beta.3 but since there are some breaking changes I'd like first to deploy with this version.

I've tryied the `overrideTestingModule` solution but it didn't worked for me. I've also tryied to add the `MdDialogModule()`, still nothing. I've tryied both combinations , with `.forRoot()` and without it.  For both `MaterialModule`  and `MdDialogModule()` but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include your `ConfirmDialog` in your test module's `entryComponents` and `exports`.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  exports: [ConfirmDialog],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmDialog],    
  declarations: [ConfirmDialog],
});
```

Comment: Hmm, `exports` seems not to be a property of `TestModuleMetadata` (anymore). I guess that means exports of the testing module wouldn't have any effect whatsoever.